# Two users behind same NAT (PSK or EAP) - strongswan

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, openvpn, strongswan

I have a strongswan implementation and am running into an issue where when there are two users behind the same NAT, the second one "kicks off" the first one.  I was able to resolve the issue using:

- Machine Certificates.
- EAP-MSCHAPv2 with unique usernames.

The problem with EAP is that hte usernames have to be unique.  "Bob" and "Bill" work fine behind a NAT, however two devices logged in as "Bob" kick each other off (the second device works but the first one stops pinging out).  Each user is assigned a unique virtual address from a pool

This is a problem because I want to provision hundreds of devices with a generic username\password.  I'm sure PSK could also be used but last time I've tried PSK, two devices with the same PSK would boot each other off.

I prefer to use IKEv2 but can do IKEv1\L2TP if I need to.  I would think that this is possible because Strongswan can just figure out how to re-encrypt the return packets using the SPI.

Comment: Have you find any solution yet ? i am stuck in a similar issue. I have PSK and EAP conn. 
Connecting EAP connection kicks off the PSK. 

I opened an issue: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/908906/strongswan-connecting-psk-eap-at-a-time